# Default Jhipster app - useless implements Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, entity, jhipster

The default `User` entity class generated by Jhipster (version 6.7.1) extends `AbstractAuditingEntity` and implements `Serializable` .

Yet, Visual Studio Code displays the following warning :

```
Redundant superinterface Serializable for the type User, already defined by AbstractAuditingEntity
```

Indeed, navigating to the definition of the `AbstractAuditingEntity` class, it can clearly be seen that `AbstractAuditingEntity` already implements `Serializable`.

So my question : is this `implements Serializable` **needed** in the User class or can it be safely **removed**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is theoretically tricky.

Right now, that `implements` statement is really redundant. `Serializable` matters when you intend to use the "built-in" Java serialization mechanism. And that mechanism will check your objects at runtime for their concrete type, and the only thing that matters to that mechanism is whether some object implements that interface or not (and not whether that is "inherited", or "just on that class").

Theoretically, *not* having the redudant declaration could lead to problems when that *base* class changes. Meaning: what if `AbstractAuditingEntity` is reworked at some point, and its `implements Serializable` part is removed? Then it would be essential that `User` says so on its own.

But as said, that part is rather theoretical: your base class shouldn't change in such a way. And if it does, you are probably looking at a plethora of incompatibility issues anyway!

Yet, as shown, both options, keeping the statement, or removing it can be seen to be meaningful.

Thus, I would look at this from a pragmatic point of view.

So, the answer your question, you should ask a different question: *Am I going to re-generate that `User` class frequently, or do I just generate it once, and then keep editing it manually?*

Case 1: the file keeps being generated. Then simply accept what the tool is doing (if you can't change that somehow) and go with the warning.

Case 2: after generation, you become the owner of that file. Then I would prefer it to be "warning free", thus remove the `implements` statement.

Comment: I understand. I left it for now, I don't want to mess things up. Thanks for the help !

Comment: You are very welcome. This was an interesting question, the kind of stuff that often gets overlooked, but that has some good points in it to think about!